# Plot multiple columns with different colors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, scatter-plot

I have a 372x15 matrix. I'm trying to graph this in such a way that columns 1-14 will be on the x-axis with different colors for each column, whereas the 15th column will be treated as the y-axis. For example, the plot with follow (x1, y), (x2, y) so on so forth, where x1 is all the data points in column 1. This is a simple scatterplot. How can I do this on MATLAB?

Comment: What do you mean by the "15th column will be on the y-axis"?

Comment: Made it a bit clear but the data on the 15th column and the correspondant other columns will be plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do that is just use `plot(A(:,1:end-1), A(:,end), '.')`. Here's an example:

```
A = [(1:14)-.6*rand(372,14) ((1:372).'+rand(372,1))]; % example A. Uses implicit expansion
plot(A(:,1:end-1), A(:,end), '.') % do the plot
axis tight % optionally make axis limits tight
```

[image]

The above cycles through [the 7 predefined colors](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html). If you prefer to customize the colors, set the `'ColorOrder'` property of the axes before calling `plot`, and use `hold on` to prevent Matlab from resetting it:

```
clf % clear figure
cmap = autumn(size(A,2)); % example colormap
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', cmap); % set that colormap
hold on % needed so that the colormap is not automatically reset
plot(A(:,1:end-1), A(:,end), '.')
axis tight
```

[image]

You can specify different markers or marker sizes; see [`plot`'s documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

Comment: The idea here is correct, though I interpreted that the OP wanted to have the vertical `y` axis value to be determined by the last column, instead of the horizontal `x` axis. Could probably be changed by swapping the argument order when calling `plot`.